# Several XML requests in one page on Django project

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, django, xmlhttprequest

I have a Django project . In this project I have created a form with several fields. Than I have to create 3 xml requests using input data of the form's fields and send it by the POST method. After that I have to receive 3 xml responds and display the result on the webpage.
Please help me to understand how to do this. As I understand the better way to create requests is XMLHTTPREQUEST. But maybe you know a better way how to do this. Also I do not understand if it possible to make several xml requests on one page using  XMLHTTPREQUEST?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean `create xml requests by POST method`?

Comment: Sorry, I edit my post